# How to convert ionic mobile app to angular web app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic-native

I need a way or guide to transfer my ionic web app to angular web app.

Online there are some tutorial for converting angular to ionic but I want to do opposite of it.

I tried to move code from ionic to angular app but there are several components and libraries which are specific for ionic and not available in angular so I don't know what could be the replacement of that.

Mainly I need ui from that mobile app.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could do two things. You can replace your Ionic components with Angular materials en use a Angular only componets! Or you can load ionic as a CDN in your new Angular project and keep on using your ionic components. Just place the script tag in your index file and CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in your angular app.module.ts. Hope this helpt you.

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@6.0.0/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>`
`schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]`